# Why do not all computers show up on net view?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, command-line

I have a wired LAN network with some networking issues. In dealing with them, I have used `net view` in Command Prompt to try to see all of the computers on the network.

There are four computers on the network: XP1, XP2, XP3, and Win7. (I am doing this on Win7).

- When using `net view`, Win7 can see XP2 and itself.
- When looking at the network in Network and Sharing Center, Win7 can see and share with XP2, XP3, and itself.
- Using `\\XP1`, Win7 can also see and share with XP1.
- All of the computers can be seen if `nbtstat -a "Computername"` is used in Command Prompt.

Why can I see the two other computers (XP1 and XP 3) in either the Network and Sharing Center or by using `\\XP1`, but not when using `net view`?

To clarify, they are all in the same workgroup. Some of them can see each other, and each computer can, in some way or another, see or be seen by at least one other computer in the group, generally more.

Comment: is it because they have no shares?  Or os password protected sharing set up?

Comment: I can access the shared folders on both XP1 and XP3, so I don't think so.

Comment: Maybe they have disabled [Network Discovery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-network-discovery#1TC=windows-7)?

Comment: I've heard rumours that the Domain Master Browser system that net view queries doesn't work very well in general. Have not played with it much personally though, so I can't say for sure either way.

Answer (score 2):

The reason has to do with the architecture of Microsoft Windows networking. In your setup, Windows uses a rather mundane way of enumerating network devices: Broadcasting. Virtually, it broadcasts a message on the network asking any device that can hear it to report in.

Of course, you probably expect a fast response, so `net view` waits a split second before listing every device that has reported in. The Network view, however has the luxury of waiting as long as you keep it open and updating its device list in real time. Hence, if it takes longer for a couple of devices to report in than the amount `net view` waits, you get a partial list. But Network can still list devices even if they report in late. They appear late, but if that latency is just a split second, you don't feel it.

It is of course possible for some computers to become stealthy by actively refusing to respond to the device discovery broadcast message. That's what a firewall can do.

Answer (score 0):

Net view allows you to see a list of computers in your **current domain**, while nbtstat is designed to help you troubleshoot NetBIOS name resolution problems and uses several options to do this (i.e. local cache, DNS, WINS, etc.)
Most likely these set of computers are all in distributed among different windows GROUPs which are seem to be registered with the single machine that you are using to access the shares but not one another. 
I would recommend that you access each of these machines and make sure that they are all parts of the same windows GROUP to simplify and be able to see one another from every single computer.

Comment: They are all in the same work group, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: Network properties. Install protocol, LAN/IPX. Ipv6. All p.c's same protocols.

Comment: @Brok3n, the [IPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internetwork_Packet_Exchange) protocol was used on Novell Netware networks, which were once popular in enterprise enviroments, but not now; adding that protocol is unlikely to benefit him.